# 3D slicer medical Imaging software

Tags: dice, imaging

I want to calculate the dice similarity coefficient using 3D slicer. However,
I cannot find how to upload the test and reference segment. when I click on a reference segment and when I want to select a segmentation which has two options: rename new segmentations or delete current segmentation. I do not know what to do to find my prepared reference segment.
I would be grateful if someone could help me out.

when I click on a reference segment and when I want to select a segmentation which has two options: rename new segmentations or delete current segmentation. I do not know what to do to find my prepared reference segment.
I would be grateful if someone could help me out.